# Scala: expressions vs method/function comparison

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My post title terminology probably isn't correct. But basically, I can do a self-join that only compares `ids` with those observed (48-72) hours afterward. I do that with this code:

```
df.join(df.select(col("id") as "id_b",
                  col("timestamp") as "timestamp_b"),
           (to_timestamp(timestamp).cast(long) + 172800) < (to_timestamp(timestamp_b).cast(long)) && 
           (to_timestamp(timestamp).cast(long)) < (to_timestamp(timestamp).cast(long) + 259200) &&
```

I've read on several SO posts that using the `expr()` is a "better" way of doing the above. Reasons were not given but I guess it's supposed to be more legible? Anyway, for the sake of knowledge, how would I convert the above into it's `expr()` equivalent? I know how to translate between the two approaches for simpler logic. The above case is beyond me due to the need to convert the timestamp to a long and I'm not sure of the syntax for that (or if it's even possible).

Also, is there a way to break up an `expr()` into multiple lines? I tried: `expr(""" <logic here> """` but that gives an EOL error.

My timestamps look like:

```
2020-07-27 02:34:52.3452
2020-10-21 13:23:55.2355
etc.
```

and are stored in a Spark DataFrame like so:

```
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: string (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example. Personally I don't find `expr` to be more readable in this case, but if you're interested in learning it, you can use the syntax `timestamp(col)` or `bigint(col)` for type casting in `expr`.

```
df.show(false)
+---+------------------------+
|id |timestamp               |
+---+------------------------+
|id1|2020-07-27 13:23:55.2355|
|id2|2020-07-28 13:23:55.2355|
|id3|2020-07-29 13:23:55.2355|
|id4|2020-07-30 13:23:55.2355|
|id5|2020-07-31 13:23:55.2355|
+---+------------------------+

val df2 = df.join(
    df.select(col("id") as "id_b", col("timestamp") as "timestamp_b"),
    expr("""
        bigint(timestamp(timestamp)) + 172800 <= bigint(timestamp(timestamp_b)) 
        and 
        bigint(timestamp(timestamp)) + 259200 >= bigint(timestamp(timestamp_b))
    """)
)

df2.show(false)
+---+------------------------+----+------------------------+
|id |timestamp               |id_b|timestamp_b             |
+---+------------------------+----+------------------------+
|id1|2020-07-27 13:23:55.2355|id3 |2020-07-29 13:23:55.2355|
|id1|2020-07-27 13:23:55.2355|id4 |2020-07-30 13:23:55.2355|
|id2|2020-07-28 13:23:55.2355|id4 |2020-07-30 13:23:55.2355|
|id2|2020-07-28 13:23:55.2355|id5 |2020-07-31 13:23:55.2355|
|id3|2020-07-29 13:23:55.2355|id5 |2020-07-31 13:23:55.2355|
+---+------------------------+----+------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks. Are there other advantages to `expr()`? The explanations I read are best summed as "legibility," and the rationale for that was the greater prevalence of and familiarity with SQL. Didn't seem necessarily true to me and I find both approaches equivalent.

Comment: An advantage is you can call Spark SQL functions/expressions that don't exist in Scala Spark. Can't list too many examples off the top of my head, but using `interval` in expr is certainly an important one

Comment: e.g. you can do something like `expr("date1 + interval 1 hour")`, but I'm not sure if you can write that in scala without expr

Comment: Actually your question will be a good use case for this - you can write `timestamp(timestamp) + interval 2 day < timestamp(timestamp_b)`